# Excel - Convert numbers to text in a pivot table (more than 4 values)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have built an Excel sheet that displays Employee's Grade Number. I also have created a pivot table based on the same data.

I would like the Grade Number to be displayed as Text in the pivot table :

```
-If value = 1 then "A" is displayed in the table
-If value = 2 then "B" is displayed in the table
-If value = 3 then "C" is displayed in the table
-If value = 4 then "D" is displayed in the table
-Else "N/A" is displayed
```

I tried using the conditional formatting but it only works for 2 values.

Could you help me by providing a VBA script or another idea?

You can find an example of the file here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06988753639886895632

Thanks,
Damien

Comment: Do you want the *Display* to be converted or the *underlying value* ?

Answer (score 0):

You might format the cells individually, say:

```
[=4]"D"
```

but I would suggest select the PT, Copy, Paste Special, Values somewhere else and then in the copy lookup the numbers from the PT in a lookup table.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I know I could format the cells individually but the report contains more than 3000 rows.... I'm looking for a way to format it automatically.

Comment: Got it but is there a way to keep the values as text in the PT?

Comment: Ok so at the end there is no way to do what I am asking for?

Comment: @DamienMorvan if it helps to have a second opinion, you cannot do what you are asking. pnuts has a good work around, but it is exactly that.